# How do I return to the previous while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, continue

```
    x, y = raw_input("Enter 2 numbers separated by a space.").split()
answer = 0
#Enter the 2 numbers to be calculated.
print "You have selected, A = "+ x + " and B = " + y + "."
while int(y):
    if (not int(y) % 2 == 0):
        # this checks if y is even or odd
        answer = int(answer) + int(x)  
        print "A = " + str(x) + " and B = " + str(y) + "."
        print "B is odd so we'll add A to the total."
        print "The running total is " + str(answer) + "."
    else: (int(y) % 2 == 0)
    print "A = " + str(x) + " and B = " + str(y) + "."
    print "B is even, so we'll ignore that number."

    x = int(x) * 2
    y = int(y) / 2

print "The product is " + str(answer) + "."

while True:

    a = raw_input("Would you like to make another calculation? Y or N")
    if str(a) == "Y" or str(a) == "y":
        continue
    if str(a) == "N" or str(a) == "n":
        print "Thank you have a nice day!"
        break
    else:
        print "Invalid entry. Ending program."
        break
```

I'm trying to get my program to go back to the top while loop if "Y" or "y" is entered for 'Would you like to make another calculation?'. So far what I have returns me to the bottom while loop. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your second loop should actually be an *outer* loop (in this case often called a "game loop").  The *entire application* loops until the user specifies to end the application.  Something like this:

```
a = "Y"
while (a == "Y"):

    ##########
    # All of your "first loop" logic goes here.
    # This is the primary "step" of any given instance of the "game".
    ##########

    # Then, prompt the user to continue or not...
    a = raw_input("Would you like to make another calculation? Y or N")
    if str(a) == "Y" or str(a) == "y":
        continue
    if str(a) == "N" or str(a) == "n":
        print "Thank you have a nice day!"
        break
    else:
        print "Invalid entry. Ending program."
        break
```

(Note: This is freehand code and I'm not entirely familiar with Python, so there may need to be some tweaking on the specifics.  This is meant to demonstrate the structure, not to be copied/pasted as production code.)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but I tried it both ways and still no luck. Instead I was getting automatic values for x and y. 6400 and 0 was my total. It didn't even ask for numbers to be entered and after asking if I wanted to do another calculation it repeated the question unless I typed "n".     I really appreciate you taking the time to look through my code!

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting the first while loop inside of the second. It'll run your calculation code first, check to see if you'd like to do another, and then return to the top of the `while True:` loop to do another calculation.

Like this:

```
while True:
    x, y = raw_input("Enter 2 numbers separated by a space.").split()
    answer = 0
    #Enter the 2 numbers to be calculated.
    print "You have selected, A = "+ x + " and B = " + y + "."
    while int(y):
        if (not int(y) % 2 == 0):
            # this checks if y is even or odd
            answer = int(answer) + int(x)  
            print "A = " + str(x) + " and B = " + str(y) + "."
            print "B is odd so we'll add A to the total."
            print "The running total is " + str(answer) + "."
        else: (int(y) % 2 == 0)
        print "A = " + str(x) + " and B = " + str(y) + "."
        print "B is even, so we'll ignore that number."

        x = int(x) * 2
        y = int(y) / 2

    print "The product is " + str(answer) + "."

    a = raw_input("Would you like to make another calculation? Y or N")
    if str(a) == "Y" or str(a) == "y":
        continue
    if str(a) == "N" or str(a) == "n":
        print "Thank you have a nice day!"
        break
    else:
        print "Invalid entry. Ending program."
        break
```

Hope that helps

Depending on what you're trying to do, and where this particular code appears in your program, it's usually advised to wrap your code inside of functions. That way, it doesn't automatically run when you import your module. You have to call a function to make the code run.

If you want to make this an executable script, you'd want to wrap the main loop code in a `if __name__ == '__main__:` block so that it only executes if it's being executed directly.

e.g.:

```
def perform_calculation():
    while True:
        x, y = raw_input("Enter 2 numbers separated by a space.").split()
        answer = 0
        #Enter the 2 numbers to be calculated.
        print "You have selected, A = "+ x + " and B = " + y + "."
        while int(y):
            if (not int(y) % 2 == 0):
                # this checks if y is even or odd
                answer = int(answer) + int(x)  
                print "A = " + str(x) + " and B = " + str(y) + "."
                print "B is odd so we'll add A to the total."
                print "The running total is " + str(answer) + "."
            else: (int(y) % 2 == 0)
            print "A = " + str(x) + " and B = " + str(y) + "."
            print "B is even, so we'll ignore that number."
            x = int(x) * 2
            y = int(y) / 2
        print "The product is " + str(answer) + "."

def run_loop():
    while True:
        perform_calculation()
        a = raw_input("Would you like to make another calculation? Y or N")
        if str(a) == "Y" or str(a) == "y":
            continue
        if str(a) == "N" or str(a) == "n":
            print "Thank you have a nice day!"
            break
        else:
            print "Invalid entry. Ending program."
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_loop()
```